# Window blocks on execute Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsprogressindicator

My problem is that my application's window blocks when I raise a method that represents values in a `NSTableView`. I want to do an animation with a `NSProgressIndicator` (spinner), but my window is blocked and spinner doesn't show animation.
I want if anybody can give me any hint? I thought in threads or something like this, but I'm not pretty sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you need some kind of multithreading. Fortunately, it's rather easy to do simple operations on threads in Cocoa.

You should look into *NSOperation* and *NSOperationQueue*.

You may find this blogpost useful: [turbo charging your apps with nsoperation](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's not exactly an iPhone app but I'll follow on that way (NSOperation).

Comment: NSOperations are good in non-touch Cocoa too. And they're very easy to implement, so although that example might not be the best one, you should be easily able to get them to work.

Comment: With your answer I could fix that problem. I had to fix another with NSAlerts in threads (that sometimes crashes the app), but I fixed it also. Thank you so much Peter :)